# Drone ignores pullrequest:created webhook sent from bitbucket cloud

Tags: continuous-integration, bitbucket, drone.io, bitbucket-cloud

My drone CI server configured a webhook for several events on a private bitbucket cloud repository, among those events are several pull request related events (create, update, decline and more). I configure the following pipeline on my repository

```
# .drone.yml
kind: pipeline
type: docker
name: default
steps:
- ...

trigger:
  event:
  - pull_request
```

I expect this pipeline to be executed when I open a pull request but this does not happen, instead drone outputs the following messages

```
{"level":"debug","msg":"webhook ignored","time":"..."}

{"fields.time":"...","latency":...,"level":"debug","method":"POST","msg":"","remote":"...","request":"/hook?secret=...","time":"..."}
```

When I decline or trigger other pull request related events I see by the debug messages drone is receiving them correctly.
When I trigger the pipeline with the push event it is correctly executed and the results are communicated to bitbucket without an issue.
When I compare the headers (for request and response) of a pull request decline event (correctly detected by drone) and a pull request create event (ignored by drone) both look very similar.

Drone version: 1.10.1
Docker runner version: 1.6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drone does not support [pull request events for bitbucket cloud](https://discourse.drone.io/t/pull-request-trigger-not-firing-to-bitbucket-cloud/5627) at the moment.

Bitbucket also has [an open issue](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-5814) about this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use directly `ref` instead of `event`

```yaml
trigger:
  ref:
  - refs/pull/*/head
```

ref: https://docs.drone.io/pipeline/triggers/